# Disable the plugin - "Delete workspace when build is done" in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testing

Can anyone provide a solution to disable the plugin - "Delete workspace when build is done" in jenkins. Though i click on the "Advanced" button and uncheck all the status like - "Success", "Unstable", "Failure", "Not built" and "Aborted", sometimes Jenkins clears my workspace. Again i need to do a clone from git into the workspace. I have the job scheduled to run every morning. Is there a way to permanently block this feature? Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: You can delete **Delete workspace when build is done** post build action completely

Comment: Thanks @Sers. I did that! Lets see if i face that issue again.